# subprocess.call() in python is used for?

Tags: python, bash, pip, subprocess, popen

```
roadSegCommand = segBin + pred_img + self.out_dir # Here we are adding 3 links
output = subprocess.call(['bash','-c', roadSegCommand])
```

Bash is not working in my pc so i used "pip" instead of "bash". If i place `-c` there, no such options `-c` is comming on console. So if i changed to `-h` it was working. But my questions are

1. Is it correct `subprocess.call(["pip","-h",roadSegCommand])`  ?
2. What is the difference between subprocess call and popen.
3. Is it a correct notation in parenthesis roadSegCommand?
4. Will i use pip instead of bash. What's the difference between them?

Comment: If we don't know what the substrings you're adding contain, how can we speak to correctness? Also, one question to a question please.

Comment: Bash is the shell, or command language interpreter, while pip is an application software to manage Python packages. They are not replaceable to each other. Which platform are you working on?

Comment: Why we use "bash" and "-c" in subprocess.call() in python? Please explain what subprocess.call do?

Comment: If bash doesn't work on your PC, then that command still won't work in Python

Comment: pip is not a bash replacement, either, so it's not clear what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subprocess is used to run OS commands

`pip -h` shows the help contents of the pip command, and takes no arguments, so 1) no, not correct

`bash -c "command statement"` will run that statement *using bash*

Python nor pip will help you to run bash commands if bash is not available to your system, so 4) they're completely separate programs entirely

All your other questions are answered by the subprocess module docs - https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html specifically, you can either `call` a process or `open` it to get its output and running status, although using run() is recommended over either

> The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the run() function for all use cases it can handle

3) yes, you have valid Python syntax